# Selecting photos with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of photos and I want check marks to appear when the photo is clicked. The page is also supposed to hide the check marks when it loads, but it doesn't do that either right now. The page is at http://lindseymotors.com/addvehicle.php

Here is the relevant JS code, but it gets inserted into the body of the HTML rather than the `head` tag where the rest of my JS goes. Is this what's causing my issues or is it a problem with the code itself? These bits of code are generated by PHP and inserted into the `body` HTML tag.

```
var allPhotos = new Array();
allPhotos[0] = '2000.mercedesbenz.clk430.0.jpg';    

var selectedPhotos = new Array();
    function selectVehicle(photoID) {
        if ( selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID) > -1 ) {
            $('#check'+photoID).zIndex(-1);
            selectedPhotos.splice(photoID, 1);
        } else {
            selectedPhotos.push(photoID);
            $('#check'+photoID).zIndex(1);
        }

    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#photo0').click(selectVehicle(0));
        $('#check0').zIndex(-1);
    });
```

Of course there are 17 photos on the page itself, but the code is the same for each photo. By default the check marks will be hidden once I get the functionality working.

Comment: The id attribute of all your images is `photo0`?

Comment: No, they are 0-17, I just only posted the code for 0 because it would be redundant.

Comment: As a side note don't use full resolution images as thumbnail images, your page is downloading over 100MB of images, that takes a while to download. Create rescaled images for the sizes you need

Comment: Yes I'm installing GD library tonight, sorry this is only temporary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [`jQuery.click(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method. You should pass a function, and not a statement.

Try using this instead:

```
$('#photo0').click(function() { selectVehicle(0); });
```

Comment: Thank you, this allowed the function to get passed but now it only works on the first picture. Can you visit the page to verify and explain why this might be?

Comment: Because the constant `0`, which is hardcoded. (You might want to use class and "data-" attribute to improve your code).

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at your code... look to the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).zIndex is not a function ... addvehicle.php:17

It means that the result you got with `$('#check'+photoID)` don't have a function 'zIndex'

Edit: Well you solved the error. But you have a logical problem when you remove a selected record...

Like the other guy said, there are better ways to do it. but with you wanna solve it now try to use the index to splice, and not the photoId...

```
function selectVehicle(photoID) {
    var index = selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID);
    if ( index > -1 ) {
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '-1');
        selectedPhotos.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        selectedPhotos.push(photoID);
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '1');
    }
}
```

and try to use thumbnails please..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep an array of selected images, you can easily do this with a css class and jQuery's toggleClass, and then when you need to reference the selected ones just select them using the correct selector.

Wrap each car into a div

```
<div class="car selected">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
</div>
```

Create a css class that will create the checkmark over the car image(using the [:after pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)) when the div has the class

```
.selected:after {
    content:' ';
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    display:block;
    background:url(http://lindseymotors.com/engine/img/check.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size:contain;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Then just toggle the class on or off using [jQuery's toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
jQuery("carDivSelector").toggleClass("selected");
```

And when you need to get the selected cars

```
var selectedCars = jQuery(".car.selected");
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(".car").click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.car {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.selected:after {
    content:' ';
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    display:block;
    background:url(http://lindseymotors.com/engine/img/check.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size:contain;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="car selected">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
</div>
<div class="car">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
</div>
<div class="car">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
</div>
<div class="car">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128" />
</div>
```